# Can a picture srcSet element stretch 100% like an img tag?

Tags: css, html

I can always stretch an image to 100% width.

I am trying the same with picture, but it's not working. I looked at MDN and it doesn't say anything about it.

I can't seem to understand why that'd be the case though, so it is possible I am doing it wrong, and maybe some other CSS rule would work. I am having a hard time googling it since I keep getting results for stretching pictures, so apologies if this is a common question.

This is the tag I am using

```
<picture class="my-image">
  <source srcSet="src" media="(min-width:960px)"/>
  <img srcSet="src" />
</picture>
```

The my-image class is not working here.

Comment: Can you provide a code sample of what you are trying? What do you mean with a picture, you will always use a <img> tag when using a picture

Comment: @NicolasM.Pardo added code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missusing the `<picture>` tag, for example the images inside will keep the `src` element, but the `<source>` tags will have priority to show in case the rule is fulfilled.

```css
.my-image {
  width: 100%;
}
.my-image img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<picture class="my-image">
  <source srcset="https://img.gawkerassets.com/post/17/2012/08/1230-everyanything.png" media="(min-width: 900px)"/>
    <source srcset="https://img.gawkerassets.com/post/17/2012/08/1230-everyanything.png" media="(max-width: 400px)"/>
 
   <img src="https://3.bp.blogspot.com/_Y8u09A7q7DU/S-o0pf4EqwI/AAAAAAAAFHI/PdRKv8iaq70/s1600/id-do-anything-logo.jpg"/>
  
</picture>
```